# Using Chicago B

Tags: natbib, biblatex-chicago, chicago-style

Should I drop `natbib` and use `biblatex-chicago` if I want to use Chicago B style referencing?

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicagoa}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={},close={}}
```

and then inline adding parentheses around my `cites` like `(\cite{Stokes2019})` - which is a bit of hack and will probably trip me up at some point.

**Update**

The `\setcitestyle` used above can be dropped with `biblatex` and `\citeparen` used instead.

Comment: What is Chicago B referencing? For full CMoS references I would probably look at [`biblatex-chicago`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) or the slightly newer `biblatex` style [`windycity`](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity). I haven't tried your code example (because it is not a full MWE), but if you load `natbib` usually `\citep{Stokes2019}` should be the better alternative to `(\cite{Stokes2019})` (with `biblatex` you would use `\parencite`).

Comment: I know that there is an author-year reference style and a notes (basically full bibliography reference in a footnote) reference style in CMoS. So I assume one of them is *A* and the other is *B*. Confusingly, the [`chicagoa.bst` from CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/chicagoa.bst) follows the CMoS *B* reference style (according to the code comments; maybe the `a` in `chicagoa` refers to the fact that the `.bst` supports the `annotation` field).

Comment: Thanks @moewe Great pointers. I'm looking into using `windycity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a flexible Chicago reference I would definitely recommend one of the two available `biblatex` implementations.

1. [`biblatex-chicago`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago)
2. [`windycity`](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity)

`biblatex-chicago` is the established go-to CMoS style which has been around for quite some time. Due to the many edge cases in Chicago style the code is quite complex, so it can be tricky to modify, but there are many options to customise the output. Note that `biblatex-chicago` should be loaded via its wrapper package and not via `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

`windycity` is a more recent style (at least it appeared only recently on CTAN) and its code does not appear to be as complex as `biblatex-chicago`'s.

For the most part the two styles produce extremely similar output, but there may well be details where the two differ. Both styles come with extensive documentation.

`biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{sigfridsson}
sit \autocite{worman}
amet \autocite{cicero}
dolor \autocite{companion}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) sit (Worman 2002) amet (Cicero 1995) dolor (Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin 1994).]

`windycity` with `reflist, autocite=inline,`

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=windycity, reflist, autocite=inline, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{sigfridsson}
sit \autocite{worman}
amet \autocite{cicero}
dolor \autocite{companion}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) sit (Worman 2002) amet (Cicero 1995) dolor (Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin 1994).]

Comment: Thankyou for the excellent examples.