# Problem with biblatex-chicago and biber

Tags: biber, biblatex-chicago

I am using texlive 2020 on windows 10. The version details
are
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.22)

I tried out this example from here:
[Using Chicago B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502604/using-chicago-b)

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{sigfridsson}
sit \autocite{worman}
amet \autocite{cicero}
dolor \autocite{companion}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, references do not show up. I tried running from the windows commandline. I get
a strange error.[image]

As you can see, biber is looking for chicago-bitblatex.tex.bcf, but the file that
exists in my directory is called chicago-bitblatex.bcf.
What is the problem?

Comment: Biber needs to be called on the file name of your `.tex` file **without the `.tex` file extension**. So try `biber chicago-bitblatex`

Comment: Thanks. That works.

Answer (score 1):

Biber needs to be called either on the file name of your `.tex` file without the `.tex` file extension or directly on the file name of the `.bcf` file with file extension. In your example both

```
biber chicago-bitblatex
```

and

```
biber chicago-bitblatex.bcf
```

would be valid Biber calls.

I find it more convenient to use the form without extension (and it is usually easier to configure editors and similar tools using the extension-less file name), so I'd use

```
biber chicago-bitblatex
```

and that's what you'll find in most answers on this site.

If you include the `.tex` in the call, Biber goes off searching for a file that does not exist.